# How can I make another HTML page appear within an HTML page when the User Scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make another HTML page appear within an HTML page when the User Scrolls down? For example, check out "http://quran.com/2/4/". In this Website,  once you click the button 'continue' below the English text, it displays more verses while keeping the file path "quran.com**/2/...**", and when you scroll down it automatically keeps on displaying the rest of verses until there are no more verses available in that file path. (In this case, the verse number ends at "quran.com/2/286). I want to create such a Web page using HTML, CSS, and Javascript only. I'll display how I have created my folders so you can give me the code.

Click the link to see image below which separate folders for each chapter number

[image: I have created]

check below image

[image: I have placed and 1 Verse in 1 HTML document.]

Comment: you could use an `iframe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is good programming practices to follow the programming convention and let the components to do their job. Even if you are welling to add html pages when the user is scrolling down is not  a good programming practice. In order to update the page content, you need to convert all of your html page data, into objects/collection such as array `var pages = array(page1, page2, page3, ...)`. And if you want more efficient way you can uses some database

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

var pageIndex = 0;

// convart all of your pages data into array of page objects as follow 
    var htmlPages = [
        // page 1
        {header:"header data for page 1", body:"body data for page 1", footer:"footer data for page 1"},
        // page 2
        {header:"header data for page 2", body:"body data for page 2", footer:"footer data for page 2"},
        // page 3
        {header:"header data for page 3", body:"body data for page 3", footer:"footer data for page 3"}
        // and other pages ....
    ];
function yHandler(){

    var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
    var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    

    
    // dispaly page if more page is available 
    if(pageIndex < htmlPages.length) {
    
        if(y >= contentHeight){
            var page = htmlPages[pageIndex];
            wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">'+ page['header'] + '<br>' + page['body'] + '<br>' + page['footer'] +'</div>';      
        }
        pageIndex++;
    }

    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
}
window.onscroll = yHandler;
</script>
<style>
div#status{position:fixed; font-size:24px;}
div#wrap{width:800px; margin:0px auto;}
div.newData{height:1000px; background:#09F; margin:10px 0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="status">0 | 0</div>
    <!-- in order to activate the scroll bar -->
    <div id="wrap" style="height: 600pt;"></div>
    <!-- Some inicial data -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to add and HTML page for each of the Blue box that appear?

Comment: I want your help with this as well::[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725184/how-to-create-a-search-box-that-opens-up-folders-and-files-in-html) Barakallahu Feekum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are kind of looking for Pushpin kind of functionality. I don't know how much are feasible with using  third party library you can use Materialize CSS which has pushpin feature exactly you are looking for.

DEMO: https://materializecss.com/pushpin.html

You can use JQUERY with it if you want. But I was just using the whole library with just java script.

Let me know if the demo help or else I would love to give you the actual code.

Comment: Yes, the demo helped. Thanks! But it would be amazing and educational if you can provide me with the actual code.