# How to create a search box that opens up folders and files in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, search-box

I want to know how I can create a RESPONSIVE (that resizes according to devices) search box in HTML, CSS, & JavaScript, etc that opens up folders and files according to the value that the user inputs. It would be helpful if you can provide me with the full code. I will demonstrate a small example using images that I created using image processing software, so you can fully understand my question.
This is how my folders are placed:
[folders placed preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaqtU.png)

The sample search box:
[search box design preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjRFd.png)

The sample search box with values for demonstration:
[search box demonstration preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXRoS.png)

What the result should be;
when the user inputs the value “2” in the “text1” field, the search box should select the “…/webpage/2” directory. And when the user inputs the value “1” in the “text2” field the search box should select the folder/file that is inside the folder which is selected by “text1” field, i.e. “…/webpage/2/1.html”. (There should be some relationship between the “text1” and “text2” fields).
Also, there should be maximum values determined for the search of the text fields: for "text1" 1-114 number and in "text2" 1-286 number.
Please provide me with full code and if any clarification is needed please reply.

The current sample code for my search box

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <div class="input-group">
      <!-- the "text1" field as displayed in the image -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter chapter no"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
      <!-- the "text2" field as displayed in the image -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter verse no"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
      <!-- the "button" field as displayed in the image -->
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">GO</i></button>
    </div>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a design problem. And as such, can fork in multiple directions in terms of implementation. Do you have any source code to show?

Comment: nope. actually I don't want the exact style of the search box that is displayed in the image, I just want the functions of it.

Comment: I literally meant an algorithm design problem. I will be clearer next time.

Comment: can u give me any search boxcode  that can do the above functions?

Comment: @GetSet  Can you help me out?